# How do I change the class of a <div> that has an ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a tabbed page in a web app where I could filter restaurants through a budget and cuisine, and the results are tabbed by meals, snacks, and drinks.

My tabs are basically buttons with their respective windows just below them.

This is the code for my tabs:

```
<ul class="nav tabs" id="tabs">
            <li id="selectMeals">
                <button href="#filterTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn meals-tab">MEALS</button>
            </li>
            <li id="selectSnacks">
                <button href="#filterTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn snacks-tab">SNACKS</button>
            </li>
            <li id="selectDrinks">
                <button href="#filterTab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn drinks-tab">DRINKS</button>
            </li>
</ul>
```

My buttons have an href to one div that will show the content which has this as the code:

```
<div class="tab-content">
            <div id="filterTab" class="tab-pane meals-tab-box">
                     <div class="results"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

My tabs are color-coordinated and what's happening is when I click on any tab, the background color of the tab-content doesn't change to the color of the tab. It's because the

```
<div id="filterTab" class="tab-pane meals-tab-box">
```

only has the class meals-tab-box when I want it to change to snacks-tab-box or drinks-tab-box whenever their corresponding buttons are clicked. (The *-tab-box CSS only have differing background colors in them)

Is there a way through Javascript to change classes of a div when referenced?

Comment: which is the tab plugin used?

Comment: If im not wrong, this is with Bootstrap of Twitter.

Comment: Yup twitter bootstrap, sorry I left that out...

Comment: Have you tried catch tabs events and handle through them?

Comment: I haven't tried anything in code but what I've been thinking is when, for instance, the drinks-tab is clicked, I'll call a document.getElementById("filterTab").className= "drinks-tab-box"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [show event](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs) of the tabs widget and try something like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    var $filterTab = $('#filterTab');
    var $filterBtns = $('#tabs').find('button[href="#filterTab"]');
    var filterClasses = $filterBtns.map(function () {
        return this.className.match(/[^\s]+-tab/) + '-box'
    }).get().join(' ');
    $filterBtns.on('show', function (e) {
        var $btn = $(e.target),
            clazz = e.target.className.match(/[^\s]+-tab/) + '-box';
        var clazz = $filterTab.removeClass(filterClasses).addClass(clazz);
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d7vMm/)

Comment: works perfect in the fiddle but i can't make it work on my actual codes.

Comment: @nutellafella then there is some difference between your code and the fiddle... can you check the bootstrap version used and whether the html really matches what you have

Comment: @nutellafella unless the issue is recreated there is nothing much that can be done

Comment: @nutellafella then please share your solution so that we can also have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, you could manipulate it like this for example:

```
$('.tab li').removeClass('selected');
$('#selectMeals').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch and handle the tabs events of Bootstrap so:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

You can change tab's classes inside event, can use jQuery to change classes.

Also, you have `show.bs.tab` event, more details of this here:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs